# NHibernate: Find dirty collections

Tags: nhibernate

I know how to [find dirty properties](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/finding-dirty-properties-in-nhibernate.aspx) using NHibernate, but it doesn't seem to work for collections (i.e. to find out if items have been added or removed from a collection).
Anyone know how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var ipc = theEntity.TheCollection as IPersistentCollection;
var isDirty = ipc.IsDirty;
```

However, keep this in mind (from the XML doc):

> Note that this is only reliable during the flush cycle, after the collection elements are dirty checked against the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I won't give you a precious example. I do not have Visual Studio opened right now to test it. You should study NHibernate.Type.CollectionType.IsDirty method.